# How to convert Long Double to String in swift

Tags: swift, string, double

I would like to print data Double in Swift, but the output is always 4.444444444444e+24, not a real number.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please show your code, the input and the expected output.

Comment: let data1 : Double = 44444444444444444.0
        let data2 : Double = 1000000.0
        let data3 = data1 * data2
        print(data3)//4.44444444444444e+22

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the *question,* not to the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An even easier approach to format your Doubles without scientific notation would be to use `String(format: "%.0f", data)`

Note that Double cannot hold `44444444444444444.0` correctly, therefore you would probably get something like `44444444444444448` as output.

To get correct results you should use `NSDecimalNumber`, like this:

```
let decimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: "44444444444444444.0")
print(decimalNumber.stringValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you...
This code converts a number from scientific format to normal format

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
let finalNumber = numberFormatter.number(from: "\(1e+07)")
print(finalNumber!)
```

This is the result: 10000000

Comment: let data1 : Double = 44444444444444444.0
        let data2 : Double = 1000000.0
        let data3 = data1 * data2
        print(data3)//4.44444444444444e+22

Answer (score 0):

@Skytect's answer is almost correct. It is just missing one step. Try the following code

```
let data1 : Double = 44444444444444444.0
let data2 : Double = 1000000.0
let data3 = data1 * data2

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
let num = NSNumber(value: data3)
let finalNumber = numberFormatter.string(from: num)
print(finalNumber!)
```

Answer (score 0):

More Class and Class func way

```
class Formatter {
  static let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    $0.minimumFractionDigits = 0
    $0.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    return $0
  }(NumberFormatter())

  class func string(from double: Double) -> String {
    let nsNumber = NSNumber(value: double)
    guard let formattedString = numberFormatter.string(from: nsNumber) else { fatalError("Should never happen")  }
    return formattedString
  }
}
```

**Usage**
UITextField.text = Formatter.string(from: double)